# Developing sharepoint web parts inside windows 8?

Tags: sharepoint, windows-8

After some trial and error, followed by some research, it seems Visual studio will not allow development of Sharepoint WebParts on anything but a Windows Server 2008 or Windows Server 2012 machine (i.e. it must be running a Sharepoint install, which is restricted to those O/S's)

My current machine is running Windows 8, so as I see it, running a virtual machine is my only option?

Would appreciate a confirmation of this, unless anyone has any suggestions otherwise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apps for SharePoint 2013 can be developed without an installation of SharePoint on the OS. 
Otherwise you have to use a Virtual Machine with a SharePoint Server running on it.

Possible duplicate/More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381979/do-i-need-to-have-sharepoint-2013-installed-on-my-local-machine-for-web-part-dev)

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I did a sharepoint webpart,  but from what I remember you just need to get your hands on the sharepoint dlls:  check this: http://www.techerator.com/2011/02/how-to-perform-sharepoint-development-on-a-client-workstation/